# How to parse images interspersed with text in a HTML DOMDocument?

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse a field that has images in place of some letters and numbers. It could be the starting letter of a paragraph, a fancy image of that letter, or it could be a letter or number has an image replacement in the middle of the text. For example, the phrase

```
"Four scores and 7 years ago"

<img src=/img/F.png>our scores and <img src=/img/7.png"> years ago
```

With images replacing some of the letters and numbers.

I'm correctly able to parse the Letter or Number that I want to replace the image with in the text field, but I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to go about it. This is based off of an example in the PHP docs:

```
if ( ! strcmp('Text Field', $label)) {
   $img_tags = $divs->item($i + 1)->getElementsByTagName('img');
   $num_images = $img_tags->length;

   for ($img = 0; $img < $num_images; $img++) {
       if ($img_tags->item($img)->hasAttributes()) {
           $img_tag = $img_tags->item($img)->getAttribute('src');
           if (preg_match('/name=([a-zA-Z0-9])/', $img_tag, $matches)) {
               // XXX So here I have $matches[1] which contains the letter/number I want inserted into the parent node in the exact place of the <img> tag
               $replacement = $page->createTextNode($matches[1]);
               $img_tags->item($img)->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $img_tags->item($img));
           }
       }
   }
}
```

---

**Extended example:**

Lets say I hit a line as such:

```
<div class="label">Title</div>
```

I know the next field will be a text field

```
<div class="value">
  <img src=/img/F.png>our scores and <img src=/img/7.png"> years ago
</div>
```

I'm trying to grab the paragraph and turn the images into the letters that I parse from the image names.

Comment: Please give a text example of the html code here. This will make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Sure, lets say I hit a line as such:

     `<div class="label">Title</div>`

I know the next field will be a text field
    `<div class="value"><img src=/img/F.png>our scores and <img src=/img/7.png"> years ago</div>`

I'm trying to grab the paragraph and turn the images into the letters that I parse from the image names.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. However it is still not possible for us to understand what you are trying to do. Where is the connection between the html markup you give and the php code you cite above? Where do $label, $divs come from? Vital information is missing, so no answer can be given.

Comment: $label isn't relevant to the question beyond being one of many conditionals found on the page. If you read the code you will see on the second line that divs is a nodelist, and from that i'm getting a nodelist of image tags, parsing them for the letter/number that i'm looking to substitute into the parent node in place of the image tag.

Comment: Answer: use saveXML and then parse it with regular expressions. This replaces much of my code above.

`$node = $dom->saveXML($divs->item($i));
$preg_match('/name=(\w+)&/', $node, $match);
$fixed_node = preg_replace('/<img.*?>/', $match[1], $node, 1);
`
Count the image tags and wrap it in a for loop if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

may be using of str_replace is the better way.

```
$source = "<img src=/img/F.pNg>our scores and <img src=/img/7.png\"> years ago";

preg_match_all("/<.*?[\=\/]([^\/]*?)\.(?:png|jpeg).*?>/i", $source, $images);

$keys = array();
$replacements = array();

foreach($images[0] as $index => $image)
{
    $keys[] = $image;
    $replacements[] = $images[1][$index];
}

$result = str_replace($keys, $replacements, $source);

// Returns 'Four scores and 7 years ago'
print($result . PHP_EOL);
```